# Ubuntu 16.04 Compiz using 100% CPU and RAM

Tags: 16.04, compiz, ram

Running ubuntu 16.04. After 12 hours of running, i find compiz is maxing my CPU out and eating all 8gb of my ram. This causes Unity to crash and I have to restart the lightdm service to fix this.

I have tried resetting compiz, disabling sync to v black. Neither of these work, any ideas??

Comment: I have the same problem. Seems to happen after it wakes up from being suspended. Not all the time, just the times when I don't have time to reboot.